# Online Content Management Database for Media and Literature

Tags: database, cms, wordpress, mediawiki

As part of research project, I'm looking to manage media (images, video, sound) and literature (a screenshot with DOI or links to the source) I collect into an online database for myself and others to see.

I'm currently using a reference manager (Papers.app) on my local devices for literature. And Pinterest for visual reference. It's frustrating to manage multiple systems with fixed schemas, on and offline, when I'm consistently dealing with files I want to share, find, categorise and tag, and add new fields for extra comments, source links or notes.

An exemplary site, ironically enough is a static HTML database compiled about a decade ago here to manage artworks http://www.mindatplay.co.uk/index.html. However this would have been put together completely by hand.

What systems can anyone recommend to achieve this? Ideally out of the box, and able to be run off a personal server. Even a good Wordpress theme anyone uses for their research collection?

Options considered:

- WordPress with advanced custom fields (ACF)—however this takes time to write into an existing theme. Unless there are flexible themes out there that go well with ACF?
- MediaWiki—great options, especially [automatic taxoboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Automatic_taxobox).

An ideal checklist:

- Categories and tags
- Accepts all kinds of media—images, video, sound, hosted videos
  (Vimeo, YouTube), PDFs
- Extra fields for additional details or links
- Visual representation beyond lists (e.g. grid view, visualisation, map)
- Ability to navigate by a custom field, tag or category
- Can be personally hosted on a server / easily backed-up

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a preferred OS or budget?

Comment: Cheers @Undo, preferably on a Linux+Nginx+PHP+MySQL (LEMP) stack. Budget as minimal as possible, it's not for commercial purposes.

Comment: What is "DOI" in first sentence?

Comment: Sorry @BasilBourque for the jargon, they're identifier links (Digital Object Identifier)—so rather than reproduce the source i.e. download and re-upload (book, article, media, and so on) you can use a DOI link which goes straight to the source https://www.doi.org commonly found on academic papers.